# React hooks are overwritting object array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, wit.ai

I'm trying to code a chatbot interface using React hooks and Wit.ai.

I have tried setting the messages imperatively (setMessages([...messages, currentValue]) but that doesn't work either. Here's the code:

```
const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState('');
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);


const handleChange = (event) => {
    setCurrentValue(event.target.value); // handling input change
}

const sendMessage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (currentValue.trim() !== '' || currentValue.trim().length > 1) {
        witClient.message(currentValue).then(data => {
            setMessages(() => [...messages, {text: currentValue, sender: 'user'}]); // here i set the user message
            if (data.entities) {
                setMessages(() => [...messages, {text: 'message from bot', sender: 'bot'}]); // this line seems to overwrite the user message with the bot message
                setCurrentValue('');
            }
        });
    }
    document.querySelector('input').focus();
}
```

When I handle the bots response it overwrites the users message.

Comment: p.s. if anyone wants to know my wit ai access token i can send it to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access `messages` after the `if statement` you're actually overwritting the first changes, cause `[...messages, {text: currentValue, sender: 'user'}]` will only be reflected in the next `render`. Set your changes all at once to prevent this

```
const sendMessage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (currentValue.trim() !== '' || currentValue.trim().length > 1) {
        witClient.message(currentValue).then(data => {
            let newMessages = [...messages, {text: currentValue, sender: 'user'}]
            if (data.entities) {
                newMessages = newMessages.concat({text: 'message from bot', sender: 'bot'})
                setCurrentValue('');
            }
            setMessages(messages)
        });
    }
    document.querySelector('input').focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are relying on prior values you can use functional pattern for setting state like below:

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

```
        setMessages((priorMessages) => [...priorMessages, {text: currentValue, sender: 'user'}]);
======================================
        if (data.entities) {
            setMessages((priorMessages) => [...priorMessages, {text: 'message from bot', sender: 'bot'}]);
```

Comment: i didn't know about this, should probably check out the docs. thanks!

Comment: Lesser known feature as its not published in the guide but rather digged in somewhere, just found it: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates